# Craft 2 - Date Comparison In Criteria - Impossible to access an attribute ("today") on a string variable (">=")

Tags: templating, entries, datetime, craft2

I am working with a template in Craft 2, and I am setting up the criteria for entries to be displayed.
Here is my code (below).

```
{% set today = now|date('Y-m-d') %}

{% set criteria = {
    section: 'bulletin',
    order: 'postDate',
    expiryDate: '>=' . today
} %}

{% set initialEntry = craft.entries(criteria).first() %}
{% set finalEntry = craft.entries(criteria).last() %}
```

I get this error:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("today") on a string variable (">=").
```

How would I set expiryDate >= today?

Comment: In Twig, `~` is the concatenation operator! You can also use `">= #{today}"`, which Twig refers to as "string interpolation." This looks fine, otherwise. 

Comment: Ah!  Thanks so much.  I was still in PHP mode.  :)